# Why when I move my UILabel to a certain point, does it get moved when I enter full screen mode?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

Example project here: http://cl.ly/1n211V1e433G

I'm building an app where you can slide label in the middle up or down using a `UIPanGestureRecognizer` that adjusts the constant for an `NSLayoutConstraint` for how far the text is from the bottom.

```
- (IBAction)labelPanned:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)sender {
    CGPoint p = [sender locationInView:self.view];
    p.y -= sender.view.frame.size.height / 2.0;

    self.labelDistanceFromBottomConstraint.constant = -p.y + [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height - 250 + self.textToReadLabel.frame.size.height;
}
```

I have that constraint as less of a priority than two constraints that dictate that it must be greater than or equal to 50 from the top or bottom. Basically stronger constraints that make sure it doesn't go too high or too low.

When the user enters full screen mode the text label should stay in place and not move. It works great as shown in the example project, *except when the label is moved to the top*, where when full screen mode is entered it slides up.

Why is this? How can I stop this behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its because, you have set the `UILabel` constraints to resize from top too that is  causing the `UILabel` to adjust from Top when the view frame changes when you do Full Screen, so `Remove the Top constraint` and instead you can try stop panning to certain `y position` for example

```
- (IBAction)labelPanned:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)sender {
       CGPoint p = [sender locationInView:self.view];
       if(p.y<150.0)return;
}
```

**Edit**

Point is you should not put constraint for the label to adjust from top, so **Remove the Top constraint** it will not adjust automatically while you go to fullscreen.

Comment: Not to mention in the project if you put `p.y < -100` for example the same result happens.

Comment: @DougSmith I think you missed one point `Remove Top Constraint`, if you remove the constraint and stop the label to go beyond, and the value I have put is just example of doing it.. But if you remove top constraint, the label doesn't move up on full screen.. Did you try that.. ?